# Return all results matching text in one column and zero in another

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to return rows where in column C there is "ACMA" and in column T is "0".
[image]

It should be listed as below in other sheet:
[image]

Comment: I imagine a lot of the issues you're seeing are caused by the fact you're looking for `0` in a cell. In a lot of cases, an empty cell will also evaluate to `0`. Might be worth considering an alternative numbering system or adding a third criteria that the `cell <> ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @CLR mentioned you'll need to check if column T is returning 0 because it's blank or because it's actually 0. For this solution I checked the length of the value in the cell <> 0 (i.e. blank).

```
Sub ReturnMatches()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow1 As Long, newRow2 As Long
Dim x As Long

'don't know the names of your sheets so adjust accordingly
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

'determine last row of data sheet
lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastRow1
    
    'check to see if it is a match
    'for T, also check length of value in cell <> 0 (i.e. blank)
    If _
        ws1.Cells(x, 3) = "ACMA" And _
        ws1.Cells(x, 20) = 0 And Len(ws1.Cells(x, 20).Value) <> 0 Then
        
        'define first blank row of 2nd sheet
        newRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        'copy matching information to first blank row
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, 1) = "ACMA"
        ws2.Cells(newRow2, 2) = ws1.Cells(x, 4)
        
    End If
    
Next x

End Sub
```